# Word for when something has no purpose other than to look pretty?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, adjectives, synonyms

I'm trying to describe a character who is a young actress. she is exploited in the industry and basically has no purpose other than a means of 'looking pretty' or just being 'another pretty face'?? I can't think of a word for it?

I keep thinking maybe mannequin but that's not exactly correct??? or something along those lines?

Please help!

Comment: You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: [Eye candy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/eye-candy).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul That deserves to be an answer in my opinion

Comment: @BoldBen: I had written it as an answer, but when I was going to post it, I saw that fev had already spotted the dupe (and eye candy is already suggested there). :)

Answer (score 3):

You might try *ornamental*

[(Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ornamental)

> beautiful rather than useful:
> *a bowl of ornamental china fruit,
> The handles on each side of the box are purely ornamental (= they are
> for decoration only).*

Comment: And if you're looking for a noun, *ornament* works, as in the phrase "[neither use nor ornament](https://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/neither+use+nor+ornament.html)".

Comment: *decorative* and *decoration* work too.